# ROS Answers SE migration: move_base_node

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was going through the code base of ROS navigation. I have some difficulty understanding the name field and type field for running a node in a launch file.

For example, I run the move_base node using the following line in my launch file.

> node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen"

However, when I look at the source code for move_base, it has a file named move_base_node and during initialization as well is called "move_base_node"

> ros::init(argc, argv, "move_base_node");

But the executable that is present in my devel folder is called "move_base". I wonder how the naming is supposed to work and how did it get changed.

The CMakelists file also contains "move_base_node" and not "move_base".

Thank you for your time.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191948/move_base_node/) by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1133 on 2014-09-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's due to the set_target_properties(move_base_node PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME move_base) function in the CMakeLists.txt file.

---

Originally posted by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) with karma: 1133 on 2014-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2